# Any way to invalidate the high watermark value on a datasource?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I've realized that a lot of data was missing from a view I'm using as a data source to populate an index, due to using an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`. But since the data uses `ROWVERSION`, these rows are before the current high watermark value of the data source/indexer.

So rather than rebuild the entire index, I'd like to invalidate the current high watermark value, so that it will just pull in all of the data from this data source (this index pulls in data from multiple data sources).

I tried deleting/creating the underlying datasources, but this didn't seem to pull in the new data.

Is this possible? Or will I need to rebuild any indexes that pull data from these data sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset the indexer high-water mark state, use the [Reset Indexer API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/reset-indexer), or its equivalent in .NET SDK.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Was not able to able to find that when I was digging for a solution.